# SVN tag files selectively

Tags: linux, svn

Gurus- We have a process to push only the modified files to integration and production environment. We will have to use 'Tag' mechanism. The process is to push the files along with the folders integration environment and another UI deployment process execute shell scripts to copy the files to respective folders and then run Make utility or ANT.

For e.g. /root/dev/scripts/ folder have files f1 and f2 in the branch, this branch can be used by multiple developers at the same time. If suppose only file f1 is modified , I should be doing the following steps.

1) Identify the files modified.
2) Create a tag out of the files selectively. In this example tag should contain /root/dev/scripts/f1.

**Precisely my question is, how we can selectively find files and add to tag retaining the folder structure?**

Comment: This question is a bit broad, you might want to consider to post some of your scripts and where you run into problem. Have you tried something already? for instance, you could ask how to use SVN to list which files are modified...

Comment: @Jaap Yes, I have asked my team to follow a process while check-in the files . They will put in the comments [USER][IT][Comments]. I run a shell script. The script will pick the files based on IT (iteration#) in the comments. It creates a folder structure without files, copy the files it picked up from SVN to respective folders and then copy to TAGS. I'm not liking this process so was looking around if somebody has really good process.